# CSS light box Form holder

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, lightbox

I've tried to implement an email form to a popup light box, but whenever I got to enter some information into the form, the light box disappears but the Overlay still stays, so it doesnt fully close. I've tried to make sure that only the "close" button shuts the lightbox and not clicking on any of the field forms.

Anyone got any suggestions or any thoughts to why its doing this?

Codes here;

HTML form....

```
<div id="quote">

<h1>Ask me for a quote...</h1>
<p>Click on the link below and fill in the form for a quote and I'll get in touch.
<br>


<a href="javascript:void();"  
onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='block';     document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='block';">Click here for a Quote...</a>


<div id="underlay">

</div>
<div id="lightbox">
<div id="stylized" class="myform2">
<form id="form1" action="mail.php" method="POST">

<label>Name
    <span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name">
<label>Email
    <span class="small">Enter a Valid Email</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="email">
<label>Phone
    <span class="small">Add a Phone Number</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="phone">

<br />
<br />

<label>Course Type 
    <span class="small">Please selcet the preferred course  </span>
</label>

<select name="course" size="1">
<option value="starter">Starter Course</option>
<option value="tuition">Personal Tuition</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<label>Prefered day
    <span class="small">Please choose a preferred day    </span>
</label>
<select name="days" size="1">
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesdays</option>
<option value="Sunday">Sundays</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<br />


<label>Message
    <span class="small">Type Your Message</span>
</label>
<textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

<button type="submit" value="Send" style="margin-top:15px;"  class='splash'>Submit</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('underlay').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='none';">Close</a>
</div>
```

> This is the CSS

```
#underlay{
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
-moz-opacity:0.5;
opacity:.50;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
#lightbox{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:25%;
width:50%;
height:500px;
background-color:#fff;
padding-top:30px;
}
```

Anyones got any ideas that would be greatly appreciated!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine `here`: http://jsfiddle.net/HLLVt/. Maybe try hard refreshing (CTRL + F5) or a different browser to see if its lack of browser compatibility.

Comment: I still can't get it, doing my loaf in, I tried playing with the js but can't get it, you'll see how annoying it gets on my test domain http://unifiedclothing.co.uk/